# Wave Equation energy time independence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, condensed-matter

I'm a bit confused about how the energy of the solution of the wave equation is constant. For a general solution of $\phi_+(x,t)$, the energy in the Hamiltonian formulation is given to be
$$H=\int[\partial_x\phi_+(x-vt)]^2dx=\int[\partial_x\phi_+(x)]^2dx$$
I'm quite confused about how it is clear that the gradient is time independent. My guess is that it is due to the partial $x$, however I'm not convinced that this reasoning is correct. Is there a way to reach see the time independence without explicitly differentiating the energy with respect to time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spatial derivative has nothing to do with the independence of time.  Any integral
$$H(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,f(x-vt)$$
is going to be independent of time, by a simple $u$-subsitution.  Let $u=x-vt$, so that $du=dx$; then $H$ can be rewritten as
$$H(t)=\int_{u\,=\,-\infty}^{\infty}du\,f(u),$$
which is just the value of $H(t)$ took at $t=0$.  Ergo, $H(t)=H(t=0)$ does not depend on $t$.